# Refer to gnu-manual page from bash

Tags: bash, osx, man, coreutils

I installed the latest GNU/Bash and gnu coreutils on Mac

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0)
```

check the coreutils with a g prefix

```
$ gls -l $(which gls)
lrwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 32 Oct 27 12:50 /usr/local/bin/gls -> ../Cellar/coreutils/8.30/bin/gls
```

When it come to `man`

```
$ man gman
No manual entry for gman
```

It fall back to error,

```
$ man man
#works but get BSD manual in year 2003 as return.
```

I am noticed that coreutils are composed of GNU fileutils, shellutils and textutils, so the manual should have a solution to be checked.

How could I refer to gnu manual from the bash.

Comment: Is `man` part of `coreutils`, ie. is there any `gman` program at all on your system? Try `man gls`, `man gln`, etc. and if they don't work, try with `man -M /usr/local/man ...`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure man is not part of coreutils but I could be wrong. MacOS uses a man configuration file in /private/etc/man.conf. Locate the bash man page you're trying to view and note the directory path. You can use mosvy's -M command to verify and then add the path to the config file. Or you can set and use your own $MANPATH variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed GNU coreutils with Homebrew on your macOS machine, you got this message at the end of the successful installation:

```
All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'.

If you really need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

Additionally, you can access their man pages with normal names if you add
the "gnuman" directory to your MANPATH from your bashrc as well:

    MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.30: 430 files, 8.8MB
```

Did you try updating your `MANPATH` variable?

After executing the suggested command, you would get the manual of GNU `ls` by typing `man gls`.

The modification to `MANPATH` is something you can put in your `~/.bash_profile` file (or wherever you update `PATH` in a similar manner).

---

The installation message above can also be read with `brew info coreutils` after installation.

Comment: I appreciate deeply your help, my master.